# QML Slider как изменять положение "движка" слайдера только если его перетаскивать?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qml, qt4

Обычно если нажать в области слайдера то в этом место перемещается и сам "движек" слайдера, нужно это убрать, и сделать только если этот "движек" перемещаем курсором по слайдеру.

Как такое можно сделать?
Пробовал добавить в Slider - MouseArea

```
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: handle
            drag.target: handle
            drag.axis: Drag.XAxis
            drag.minimumX: 0
            drag.maximumX: slider.width - handle.width

            onPositionChanged: {
                if (handle.contains(Qt.point(mouseX, mouseY))){
                    var pos = mouse.x / slider.width * (slider.to - slider.from) + slider.from
                    slider.value = pos
                }
            }
        }
```

Но это не помогло